# shell script to execute tophat protocol

Tags: command-line, scripts

So, I'm using a protocol called 'tuxedo' for RNA sequencing data analysis. It's more sort of technical question related to shell scripting. I can do that in command line and I have no issues as such. Since I am doing it in a cluster, I would like to use a script that can automate my task .

So the protocol command are as such :

1. tophat
2. cufflinks
3. cuffmerge
4. cuffdiff

   The first command does all the alignment which generates some file which I have to use for the next command `cufflinks`, then `cuffmerge` and finally `cuffdiff`.

Can anyone help me to write a simple shell script which can call each of these command and do the task.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

arguments

```
tophat -p 8 -G genes.gtf -o C1_R1_thout genome C1_R1_1.fq C1_R1_2.fq
cufflinks -p 8 -o C1_R1_clout C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam
cuffmerge -g genes.gtf -s genome.fa -p 8 assemblies.txt 
cuffdiff -o diff_out -b genome.fa -p 8 –L C1,C2 -u merged_asm/merged.gtf \
./C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C1_R2_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C1_R3_thout/accepted_hits.bam \
./C2_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C2_R3_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C2_R2_thout/accepted_hits.bam
```

where, 'p' corresponds to the number of processor the '-o' corresponds to the output directory and rest the '-g' corresponds to the annotation file that I am using to annotate my RAW reads which will be aligned.

Comment: That's all? 4 commands, no arguments, no conditions?

Comment: [edit] your post to include the complete commands

Comment: edited my post with all the commands that i use in my terminal to run the protocol

Comment: I have installed all these I mean I can all the command irrespective of the directory I'm in , as I was told to add to the path to the .bashrc file. Im not sure if that can help or not

Comment: well Im not sure if that can work i will give it a try since im already in the middle of the process ,so now I cannot abort but can you not write a shell script that can take my input as the raw reads and do further downstream analysis.I m quite naive to shell scripting apart from few basics ,so if any help then it would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The simple and fragile solution

Let us write a simple script called hailmary.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#The first line should always be just as it is above
#This script is called hailmary.sh
#because we run this script and we need to pray
#that all four commands will run correctly
#If one of them fail, you may not get the results

tophat -p 8 -G genes.gtf -o C1_R1_thout genome C1_R1_1.fq C1_R1_2.fq
cufflinks -p 8 -o C1_R1_clout C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam
cuffmerge -g genes.gtf -s genome.fa -p 8 assemblies.txt 
cuffdiff -o diff_out -b genome.fa -p 8 –L C1,C2 -u merged_asm/merged.gtf ./C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C1_R2_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C1_R3_thout/accepted_hits.bam ./C2_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C2_R3_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C2_R2_thout/accepted_hits.bam
```

1. Copy and paste all the above lines including the lines starting with
   "#" in gedit, and save as hailmary.sh.
2. In Nautilus, right click on the file you just created and select
   `Properties`. Go to `Permissions` tab and put a check mark next to
   **Allow executing file as program**.

   Alternately, in a terminal enter:

   chmod +x hailmary.sh
3. To run the script in a terminal, enter:

   ./hailmary.sh

The `./` before the name is necessary, and assumes the file is in the current directory location. If you put the file in a folder that is in the path, such as `/home/<userid>/bin`, then you won't need the `./`. If you put it somewhere else you will need to write the whole path, such as:

```
/home/<userid>/myspecialfolder/hailmary.sh
```

Note, the four commands and their arguments are in four separate lines. If you want to put them in a single line, you have to separate them by `&&` or by `;`. There is no need for `;` if they are in separate lines.

In any of these cases, the second command will not start until the first completes (or crashes!).

The problem with this approach is, it does not check if the first command ran successfully before running the second one and so on and so forth. So if `tophat` fails for some reason, the script will continue with the sequence of cufflink, cuffmerge, and cuffdiff. That is why I call this scrip `hailmary.sh`.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/bash-how-to-run-a-command-after-the-previous-finished

## Script with check for output of tophat

```
#!/bin/bash
#The first line should always be just as it is above
#This script is called hailmary2.sh
#This script runs tophat
#then checks for the existance of the output file
#If the output is found, it runs the rest

tophat -p 8 -G genes.gtf -o C1_R1_thout genome C1_R1_1.fq C1_R1_2.fq

if [[ -f "./C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam" ]]; then
    echo "tophat finished. Proceeding with the rest"
    cufflinks -p 8 -o C1_R1_clout C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam
    cuffmerge -g genes.gtf -s genome.fa -p 8 assemblies.txt 
    cuffdiff -o diff_out -b genome.fa -p 8 –L C1,C2 -u merged_asm/merged.gtf ./C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C1_R2_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./#C1_R3_thout/accepted_hits.bam ./C2_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C2_R3_thout/accepted_hits.bam,./C2_R2_thout/accepted_hits.bamfi
else echo "tophat did not complete"
fi
```

Hope this helps until someone else provides a more elegant answer.

Comment: yes i understand that issue but would it be possible to check the output from the first command which can be piped into the later one?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Is `./C1_R1_thout/accepted_hits.bam` the output file of tophat? If this file exists, can we assume that tophat completed correctly? If so, I can add a check.

Comment: yes please that would be really helpful to run the pipeline for multiple samples as of now i have less but this will increase in number .So please append the script with more ,I hope you understood my problem

Comment: I would be really nice if the tophat can align each set of raw reads first when its done with all the raw  reads and once the accepted bam .hits is made then it should go to the next since this protocol involves seeing the differential expression in a control sample vs multiple test or condition sample  , there fore I would love to know how you can provide a loop to the tophat so that it goes thorough each raw read and make bam files  out of it then it goes to the next one

Comment: I have no idea how to do what you said. This goes well beyond the original question. If you think my answer to the original question is correct, put the green Chuck mark next to it. You may want to look for a forum of other DNA sequence data analysts who understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: well its more of a scripting issues so its pretty simple for tophat should finish every raw reads , before  going to next step so its like you have to process all the files before I proceed to cufflinks and so on. So I have like multiple files which i have to read and align produce output to a directory this will keep on going till I all my files are done.hope now you can understand my issues .

Comment: Please ask a new question with more details of the problem. What did "finish every raw read" mean?  Does it mean process every file in a folder one by one? Do you want it done in a certain order? Does the folder have files that tophat should not or cannot process? I have no idea about RNA sequence work. You will have to explain everything in the new question.